# nginx redirection cycle with X-Accel-Redirect

Tags: nginx, http-headers

Trying to get nginx to work with the `X-Accel-Redirect` header. I'm getting this error:

```
*24 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/app/index.php", client: 127.0.0.1, server: project.dev, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "project.dev"
```

nginx site conf:

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name project.dev;
    root        /www/project;

    location ^~ /f/ {
        internal;
        alias /www/project/files/;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri /app/index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    include php.conf;
    include apache.conf;
}
```

/www/project/app/index.php

```
<?php
header('X-Accel-Redirect: /f/image.jpg');
exit;
```

I added `^~` to the location block, because I thought that would terminate the matching of location blocks, and therefor solve this. This might be a misunderstanding from my part.

Any idea how to fix this?

---

**Update with php.conf and apache.conf**

php.conf:

```
# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
#
location ~ \.php$ {
  fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
  fastcgi_index  index.php;
  fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  include        fastcgi_params;
}
```

apache.conf:

```
# deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
# concurs with nginx's one
#
location ~ /\.ht {
    deny  all;
}
```

Comment: This configuration works fine for me. Please provide the contents of `php.conf` and `apache.conf` since they may be interfering.

Comment: @mgorven Updated Q

Comment: Does the PHP page display if you remove the `X-Accel-Redirect` and just echo something? What URL are you accessing in the browser? What happens if you specifically access `/app/index.php`?

Comment: To be clear: you're hoping that when you go to the root in a browser, `/www/project/files/image.jpg` is served?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I failed to restart my nginx server. When I returned to this a couple of days later, it was suddenly working, and I realized it must be after a reboot. Sorry for wasting your time.

Now if I only could make it send the correct `Content-type` header..

Answer (score 0):

You haven't told nginx what index file to look for.

Try adding

```
index index.php;
```

After the root directive.

Comment: I've done that in my nginx.conf: `index  index.html index.htm index.php;`